# JQuery inconsistent relative path

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a Razor Page with a button that uses the JQuery load method.
The url path of the page includes a parent folder name
.../ParentFolder/Index.

The JQuery load method is used to fill a Bootstrap modal div with the results from a Page handler on the same Index page.

The page handler method to load from is
../ParentFolder/Index/Handler

The problem I'm having is that the JQuery button load method doesn't produce a consistent relative url path for the Page Handler.
The  URL at the button is always coded as 'Index/Handler without ParentFolder.

```
$(function () {
        $('button.details').on('click', function () {
            $('.modal-body').load(`/Index/Handler`);
        });
    })
```

The very first time the page loads and I click the button it works.
The load method adds the parent folder name and issues a network call to

.../ParentFolder/Index/Handler

However, once I reload the page or navigate back to the page the button no longer works.
Although it is the same button on the same page, the request path no longer includes the parent folder.
Subsequent network calls go directly to

.../Index/Handler  (fail 404)

If I include the parent folder path in the button's load URL, I get the opposite problem. The page won't work the first time because the folder name appears twice (ParentFolder/ParentFolder/Index) but will work after navigation (ParentFolder/Index)

I'm not very experienced with Javascript. I know I could probably check the URL properties in code and modify the folder path when needed through string manipulation, but I suspect that I'm missing something more basic. Are there any suggestions for a better way? Thanks

Comment: the correct behavior to interpret this `/Index/Handler` is appending it to the ***root path***. The root (base) path can be specified via `<base>` element inside the `<head>` section.  So no parent folder should be prefixed. I doubt that there may be some wrong assumption here. You should carefully test it again, try other urls, ...

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks @KingKing! I added the <base> element to the <head> to specify the root path (.../ParentFolder/) , and I removed the folder path from my jQuery url (Index/...). The <base> element was the simple part that I was missing. –

Answer (score 0):

the correct behavior to interpret this /Index/Handler is appending it to the root path. The root (base) path can be specified via  element inside the  section. So no parent folder should be prefixed. I doubt that there may be some wrong assumption here. You should carefully test it again, try other urls, ... – – king-king Mar 28 at 2:44